# How to load bootstrap Dual List box dynamic? jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have tried to load from ajax my data but it doesnt work

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            cargarSubModulos();

})

function cargarSubModulos() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Perfiles/CargarSubModulos",
        data: {
            modulos: $("#modal_nombre_modulo").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#modal_submodulos').empty();
            if (res.result = "ok") {
                var ca = "";
                $.each(res.data, function (index, item) {
                    ca = "<option value=" + item.subModuloId + ">" + item.nombre + " (" + item.descripcion + ")</option>"
                    $("#modal_submodulos").append(ca);
                });
            }
            console.log(res.data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
        }
    })
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Selecciona que submodulo quieres habilitar</label>
                <select class="duallistbox" multiple="multiple" id="modal_submodulos">
                                                            </select>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

that is what it show me, i load like normal select but i dont know how implement that code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFMWT.png)

Comment: can u console log `res` inside your ajax success function and show the output?

Comment: {result: "ok", data: Array(4)}
data: Array(4)
0: {subModuloId: 1, moduloId: 1, nombre: "Perfiles", descripcion: "Maestro Administrativo", estado: null, …}
1: {subModuloId: 3, moduloId: 1, nombre: "Horarios", descripcion: "Maestro Administrativo", estado: null, …}
2: {subModuloId: 4, moduloId: 1, nombre: "Estudiantes", descripcion: "Maestro Administrativo", estado: null, …}
3: {subModuloId: 5, moduloId: 1, nombre: "Materias", descripcion: "Maestro Administrativo", estado: null, …}

Comment: @harry , that is what it show me

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement you need the double equal sign.

Replace `if (res.result = "ok")` with the `if (res.result == "ok")` or `if (res.result === "ok")` to make sure the type will be compared too but in your case `==` would be enough